# run function on mousemove angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want create animation on mousemove in angularjs. I found example
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMousemove

but i want to run function.
So inside of body

```
<body data-ng-mousemove="squareRotate()">
```

And js:

```
$scope.squareRotate = function(){
  alert();
};
```

but i cant make it work. How can i manage it without   puting it inside of controller ?

Comment: where are you declaring your data-ng-app? if you put it in the body, it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't post your complete code, one can only guess. I am guessing that either the place of your body is really small, so you don't really move the move over the body, or angularjs application and controller are not properly initialised.

In order to give the html and body enough room, use the following:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I created a working demo in fiddle. The only difference is that I don't use alerts, but a counter, which increases, when you move your mouse over the field.

```
testApp.directive('testDir', function () {
    return function (scope, element) {
        var el = element[0];

        el.addEventListener(
            'mousemove',
            function () {
                alert('test');
            },
            false
        );
    }
});
```

You may try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/AfNH9/4/

If you meant something different, please specify further.

**Use directive:**

I update the example to use a directive. The directive is bound to the body tag and uses an eventListener on "mousemove". If you move the mouse over the "Result" window in fiddle, you will see the alert window. http://jsfiddle.net/AfNH9/6/

Comment: Is it possible to run that function with no controller ?. I want to animate one element on mouse move. So i have to create controller and wrap all body tag, or can I put in in global $scope and run it?

Comment: if you use angularjs, you need to define this function either in an controller (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) or a directive (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). If you don't want to use the controller, why do you use angularjs at all?

Comment: Ok i will try directive than

Comment: I updated the answer to show, how you may use a directive. Please accept the answer if it helps your issue!

Answer (score 1):

Please see here : http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:FrTqqTNoY8BEfHs9bB0f?p=preview

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
        <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.2.19"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="MainCtrl" data-ng-mousemove="squareRotate()">
        <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.squareRotate = function(){
  alert();
};
});
```

Comment: As an addition: $event object will be available in squareRotate() to indicate coordinates.